# Prove by contradiction that if $n^3$ is a multiple of $3$, then $n$ is a multiple of $3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem statement**:
Using proof by contradiction, prove that if $n^3$ is a multiple of $3$ , then $n$ is a multiple of $3.$

**Attempt 1**:
Assume that there is exist $n$ which  is a multiple of $3$ such that $n^3$ is not a multiple of $3.$

Then $n = 3k $ , $n^3 = 27 k^3 $ which a multiple of $3$, which contradicts the assumption that $n^3$ is a multiple of $3.$

**Attempt 2**:
Assume that there exist $n^3$ which is a multiple of $3$ such that $n$ is not a multiple of $3.$

Then $n = k+ 1 $ or $n= k+2.$

Then $n^3 = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1$
or $n^3 = k^3 + 6 k^2 + 12 k + 8.$

Both cases contradict the assumption that $n^3 $ is a multiple of $3.$

**Which solution is correct ? Or do both work ?**

Comment: You need to argue that both cases are covered but I believe you meant to say $n=3k+1$ and $n=3k+2$.

Comment: If you say $k+1$, then put $k$ as $2$, and the first $n^3 = 2^3 + 3(2)^2 + 3(2) + 1$ means that $3~|~n^3$ which contradicts your solution. Replace $k$ with $3k$ in each.  To yield a contradiction you've be aware that your original statement is that $p \to q$ which is that $\lnot (p \land \lnot q)$. To prove yourself, you've to show that if $p \land \lnot q$ is true then it implies that it isn't ,a contradiction! (More like what you did in your "turn 2" part.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $P,Q$ are statements then $P \implies Q$ is same as $ \neg Q \implies \neg P $.

Here $P : n^3$ is a multiple of $3$ and $Q: n$ is a multiple of $3$.

So if you want to prove it by contradiction you have to assume that $n^3$ is multiple of $3$ but not $n$ and then get a contradiction.

You can  do this by noting that every number is in the form $3k, 3k+1$ or $3k +2$. If $n$ is a not a multiple of $3$ then it has to be in the form of $3k+1$ or $3k +2$

Answer (score 1):

given statement: “If $n^3$ is a multiple of $3,$ then $n$ is a multiple of $3.$”

1. Your Attempt 1 is wrong, because it's attempting to prove the
   *converse* of the given statement.
2. Attempt 2 (“Assume (to the contrary) that there exists $n^3$ which
   is a multiple of $3$ such that $n$ is not a multiple of $3$”) does start correctly.  However, the correct translation of <$n^3$ is a multiple of $3$> ought to be <$n^3=3k+1\,$ or $\,3k+2$> instead.
3. Alternatively and equivalently, you could also start with “Suppose
   that $n^3$ is a multiple of $3,$ and assume (to the contrary) that
   that $n$ is not a multiple of $3.$”

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $n$ can be $3k+1$ or $3k+2$.

If $n = 3 k + 1$ then $n^3 = 27 k^3 + 27 k^2 + 9 k + 1 = 3 (9 k^3 + 9 k^2 + 3k) + 1$
; so $n^3$ is not divisible by $3$.  If $n = 3 k + 2$ then $n^3 = 27 k^3 + 54 k^2 + 36 k + 8 = 3 (9 k^3 + 18 k^2 + 12 k + 2) + 2 $.  So, again, $n^3$ is not divisible by $3$.  Thus we have be contradiction that if $n^3$ is a multiple of $3$ then so is $n$.